# How to store a structure of data in a template way?

Tags: c++, templates, exception, c++14

I have a templated structure in which I want to pass as a template arguments 2 reference to functions - allocator and deallocator. Is there any way I can group them in a template-like structure so there won't be a chance for them to be mismatched?

I don't want to use a normal reference to structure because then there will be a lot different instances but I want one for each pair of functions.

Example:

```
template<bool bNoExcept>
struct type_object_factory_memory_mng_funcs
{
     void *(&refAllocFunction)(std::size_t) noexcept(bNoExcept);

     std::conditional<bNoExcept, bool, void> (&refDeAllocFunction)(void *) noexcept(bNoExcept);
};

template<typename Type, bool bNoExcept, type_object_factory_memory_mng_funcs<bNoExcept> &&refMemFuncs>
struct type_object_factory ; //here instance for each rvalue object passed will be created
```

Is there a better way?

I don't want to use this:

```
template<typename Type, bool bNoExcept, void *(&refAllocFunction)(std::size_t) noexcept(bNoExcept), std::conditional<bNoExcept, bool, void> (&refDeAllocFunction)(void *) noexcept(bNoExcept)>
struct type_object_factory ;
```

Becaus this way there is a big chance that not-matching functions will be passed. Any ideas how to overcome this?

I would also like to have a specific type for exception implicitly defined for each pair of functions that could throw.

Comment: Start by checking out `std::allocator`.

Comment: Passing template argument literals -- `bool`s, function pointers/references/etc -- is supported in C++, but passing template argument types tends to be much more powerful.  `allocator`s pass a bundle of related operations in one type.  In this case, you seem to be trying to reimplement how allocators for std containers work -- a source and sink of memory allocations.  I would consider mimicing what they do (at least as a first pass).  As a bonus, your allocator will work with `std::vector`s for free.